# How to read last line of xaml textbox that has NO LINES property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've seen tons of examples about the subject all using the Lines property. I can't see the Lines property in the one I'm using only Text.

```
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtActivityLog" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I would assume it should be something like the code below, but I don't know how to finish it.

```
string lastLine = txtActivityLog.Text.Last(?);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split it by line and take the last one :

```
string lastLine = txtActivityLog.Text.Split('\n').LastOrDefault()
```